# Dynamically create div with img and append it to existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to create HTML `div` element via `createPost()` function

Then add HTML `img` element via `addElements()` function

And then append the `div` to already created `div` with `id="posts-div"`

But it seems something is wrong in my script because the `div` is not appended

This whole script is wrapped inside `$(document).ready` of course

```
var testimg = 'images/1.png'
function createPost(){
    var post = document.createElement('div');
    post.className += 'col-md-3';
    post.className += 'col-sm-6';
    post.className += 'col-xs-12';
    post.className += 'post';
}          
function addElements(){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = testimg;
    img.alt = 'post';
    img.className += 'img-responsive';
    $(post).append(img);    
}
createPost();
addElements();     
$('#posts-div').append(post);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another version which I believe is a better way.

```
var testimg = 'images/1.png';
var post;
var img;
function createPost(){
    post = $('<div/>',{ class:"col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 post" }).appendTo("#posts-div");
}          

function addElements(){
    img = $('<img/>',{ src:testimg , alt:'post',class:'img-responsive' }).appendTo(post); 
}
createPost();
addElements();
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/b8tetvhh/1/

Answer (score 1):

The variable `post` is defined inside the `createPost()` function, which means that it is out of scope when you try to append it - it only exists within the `createPost()` function. Define `post` outside of the `createPost()` function, and it will become globally accessible, and it should work.

e.g.

```
 var testimg = 'images/1.png'
 var post;
 function createPost(){
     post = document.createElement('div');
     post.className += 'col-md-3';
     post.className += 'col-sm-6';
     post.className += 'col-xs-12';
     post.className += 'post';
 }          
 function addElements(){
     var img = document.createElement('img');
     img.src = testimg;
     img.alt = 'post';
     img.className += 'img-responsive';
     $(post).append(img);    
 }
 createPost();
 addElements();     
 $('#posts-div').append(post);
```

Comment: nice ill accept your comment but i was thinking about better implementation of this, i was thinking about this to wrap in one function and add these subfunctions as methods ill search some google to see how these things works in JS :)

Comment: You could always return the post in the functions, so for example...

function createPost() { ... return post; }
var post = createPost();
...
$('posts-div').append(post);

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery your code could be :

```
var testimg = 'images/1.png'

var post = '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 post"></div>';
var img = '<img src="'+testimg+'" alt="post" class="img-responsive" '/>;

$(post).append(img);
$('#posts-div').append(post);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you think this jquery script will cost less calculation on the CPU over my JS script im asking because i was curious to know for future

Comment: Normally the vanilla script is fast than jQuery but in such simple code you can't see the difference because it will be done in miliseconds. in the other side the jquery code is simple and easy to read.